# How to execute a prepared statement that has timed out

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

In case of PreparedStatement in Java, if we set the timeout and execute the query in this way:

```
int timeout = 100;
void func() {
    try {    
        statement.setQueryTimeout(timeout);
        statement.executeQuery();
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        timeout = timeout * 2;
        func();
    }
}
```

If the query gets timed out and if you set the query timeout and try to run this code again, it fails:

```
statement.executeQuery();
```

It throws an error:

> No statements may be issued when any streaming result sets are open.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Make sure to close the `ResultSet` returned by the first invocation.

Comment: Do you have more than one resultset being open per connection ?

Comment: There is only one connection and I'm not sure how to close the ResultSet by the first invocation since the query is timing out and its throwing sql exception, hence resultset is null.

Comment: Can you post more code so that we can see it?

Comment: ya, its just a simple function: func() {  try{  "those above 2 statements" } catch(SQLException) {  incr. timeout; func() // recursively try  } }

Comment: Where is statement being created and you can not declare methods that way in java -> func(){}

Comment: Where is your query too ?

Comment: Statement is created using connection.prepareStatement(). It's just a pseudo code of what i was trying to do and the query is just a simple select query.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber The OP seems to be using MySQL, not Oracle